# Hiding MVC pages in web.config

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am taking over an MVC project for which there is no source code. All I have to do is remove all the existing functionalities of the MVC based website leaving just one page alone. Right now, I have decompiled the dll from production and I have a 'not so useful' type of code in my system which needs to be wired up completely.

I am wondering if it's possible to hide all the pages and hyperlinks through web.config just leaving the required page as such? The website looks like below:

[image]

I want to keep only the "State Fact Sheets" page removing rest of the pages. is it possible at all to do this in web.config file?

Comment: Through web.confg? Probably not. You'll probably need to adjust the view.

Comment: Thanks @mason. I just did that. Yes the _Navbar file in view should just do that.

Comment: Can you hide with specific CSS Selectors? See if there is an ID on the NAV you want to hide? Also, if the views are NOT compiled, you should be able to modify the views directly, to add custom CSS.    .nav-item { display:none;}